# Fluent NHibernate ExportSchema without connection string

Tags: database, nhibernate, configuration, fluent, schemaexport

I want to generate a database script without having an actual database connection string declared.

To do this for now i use NHibernate ExportSchema bases on a NHibernate configuration generated with Fluent NHibernate this way (during my ISessionFactory creation method):

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure();               
//Mapping conf ...
configuration.Database(fluentDatabaseProvider);
this.nhibernateConfiguration = configuration.BuildConfiguration();
returnSF = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();     

//Later
new SchemaExport(this.nhibernateConfiguration)              
                .SetOutputFile(filePath)
                .Execute(false, false, false);
```

fluentDatabaseProvider is a FluentNHibernate IPersistenceConfigurer which is needed to get proper sql dialect for database creation.

When factory is created with an existing database, everything works fine.
But what i want to do is to create an NHibernate Configuration object on a selected database engine without a real database behind the scene... And i don't manage to do this.

If anybody has some idea.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
.Create(false, false);
```

inplace of

```
.Execute(false, false, false);
```

Do not add the connectionstring property to the IPersistenceConfigurer (fluentDatabaseProvider).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used. My mistake was calling BuildSessionFactory which tries to connect to the database:

```
        var config = Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008)
          .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionManager>());

        new SchemaExport(config.BuildConfiguration())
                .SetOutputFile(filedestination)
                .Create(false, false);
```